# Shell Script to prepare unformatted data

Tags: bash, shell, sh, text-files

I have text file TEST.txt which has below data which is unformated:

```
0411 14:30:00 INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.ExecuteLogsRunnable] Executing cron report Freigabe 14:30 for cron job Freigabe 14:30 for TRE_ClientServiceGroup@TEST.fs, Businesspartner@TEST.fs
0411 14:30:02 INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.ExecuteLogsRunnable] Freigaben had no results
0411 14:30:02 INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.ExecuteLogsRunnable] Freigabe 14:30 NOT sent to TRE_ClientServiceGroup@TEST.fs, Businesspartner@TEST.fs since all reports were empty and empty reports should not be send
0411 17:03:14 INF[baag.reporting.db.DataSourceMapFactory] Datasource [itraderdbint] has been added to datasource map
0411 17:03:14 INF[baag.reporting.db.DataSourceMapFactory] Datasource [otc_sv2599] has been added to datasource map
0411 17:03:14 INF[baag.reporting.db.DataSourceMapFactory] Datasource [qlp_devp] has been added to datasource map
0411 17:03:15 INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.QuarzLogsManager] Added Trigger for QUARTZ that fires next on Tue Apr 13 08:00:00 CEST 2021 for Logs Compliance MAR Crossingprüfung/Frontrunning DI-FR
0411 17:03:15 INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.QuarzLogsManager] Added Trigger for QUARTZ that fires next on Tue Apr 13 08:20:00 CEST 2021 for Logs Compliance OR Umsatzstatistik DI-FR
0411 17:03:15 INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.QuarzLogsManager] Added Trigger for QUARTZ that fires next on Mon Apr 12 08:20:00 CEST 2021 for Logs Compliance OR Umsatzstatistik MO
```

Now i want to create Shell script which will prepare this unformated data into below format and create for example `PrepardFile.txt`. I want to separate every string with pipe operator. The first part is date format so i want this as complete string. The second part always start with `INF[` and ends with `]` or we can take the complete part without spaces starting from `INF[` and this would be my second string separated as pipe operator. The third part will be the remaining part which would be my third string. I want to add header for better understanding of what does this field value indicate:

```
DATE_FORMAT|ROW_EXECUTE|ROW_VALUE
0411 14:30:00|INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.ExecuteLogsRunnable]|Executing cron report Freigabe 14:30 for cron job Freigabe 14:30 for TRE_ClientServiceGroup@TEST.fs, Businesspartner@TEST.fs
0411 14:30:02|INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.ExecuteLogsRunnable]|Freigaben had no results
0411 14:30:02|INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.ExecuteLogsRunnable]|Freigabe 14:30 NOT sent to TRE_ClientServiceGroup@TEST.fs, Businesspartner@TEST.fs since all reports were empty and empty reports should not be send
0411 17:03:14|INF[baag.reporting.db.DataSourceMapFactory]|Datasource [itraderdbint] has been added to datasource map
0411 17:03:14|INF[baag.reporting.db.DataSourceMapFactory]|Datasource [otc_sv2599] has been added to datasource map
0411 17:03:14|INF[baag.reporting.db.DataSourceMapFactory]|Datasource [qlp_devp] has been added to datasource map
0411 17:03:15|INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.QuarzLogsManager]|Added Trigger for QUARTZ that fires next on Tue Apr 13 08:00:00 CEST 2021 for Logs Compliance MAR Crossingprüfung/Frontrunning DI-FR
0411 17:03:15|INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.QuarzLogsManager]|Added Trigger for QUARTZ that fires next on Tue Apr 13 08:20:00 CEST 2021 for Logs Compliance OR Umsatzstatistik DI-FR
0411 17:03:15|INF[baag.reporting.main.Logss.QuarzLogsManager]|Added Trigger for QUARTZ that fires next on Mon Apr 12 08:20:00 CEST 2021 for Logs Compliance OR Umsatzstatistik MO
```

I am very new to Shell script and dont know if this possbile to do with the help of shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Symonds

This response is regarding your comment asking for adding a header section and further explanation.

To add header section, you can use `echo` and create the `PreparedFile.txt` first. Then use `>>` operator to append to the file. You can copy the complete code to a file named `Script.sh` and then run it using `bash Script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "DATE_FORMAT|ROW_EXECUTE|ROW_VALUE" >  PreparedFile.txt
cat TEST.txt | sed 's/ /|/2' | sed 's/] /]|/1' >> PreparedFile.txt
```

As far as the explanation you have asked for, you can chain commands using the pipe symbol `|`. The `sed` command allows you to substitute occurrences of regular expressions you specify with a replacement. In my first pipeline following `cat` command, I use `s/ /|/2`. This means replace the second occurence of blank space with `|`. You can read more about the `sed` command usage [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Comment: thanks perfect i use Sed -i command for giving the header but your solution also works fine :)

Comment: Welcome, yes there are infinite ways to solve a problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below Shell script and see if it helps. It uses `sed` command and combination of pipes to replace second occurrence of space first and then the closing square bracket.

`cat TEST.txt | sed 's/ /|/2' | sed 's/] /]|/1' > PreparedFile.txt`

Comment: You can just use this command in terminal or paste it in a shell script and execute it

Comment: thanks very much its working fine :) Can you please explain bit this command and one more small help..i want to put header for better understanding of what does this field value indicate...i have edited my question....